# Trigger pipeline after a push on bitbucket server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I'm creating this new Job based on pipeline on jenkins. I want my jenkinsfile to be on bitbucket reposiotry : Let's say my config file is on `bitbucket.org/config.git`

The job mission is to clean install a project `bitbucket.org/myProject.git`

How can I configure the pipeline so it will trigger if any push is made in `bitbucket.org/myProject.git` and following the steps defined in `bitbucket.org/config.git`?

I do not want to create multi-branch pipeline and I do not want my jenkins file to be on the same repository than my project to compile.

My current config is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '', description: 'URL', name: 'GIT_URL')
        string(defaultValue: '', description: 'Credential', name: 'CREDENTIAL_ID')
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Initialize') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'develop', credentialsId: "${params.CREDENTIAL_ID}", url:                     "${params.GIT_URL}"
            }
        }

        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean install '
                echo 'build'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared Libraries in Jenkins. you would still need a Jenkinsfile in your code, but that would not contain any logic. It would simply refer the shared library and pass any params like git repo path.

For more information on shared libraries please refer this link https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/.

For triggering the build, you can define a trigger in your pipeline. Example :

```
triggers {
      pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
}
```

or use webhooks if you don't want to poll.

Comment: Actually having code used by jenkins is not an option for me, since we want the projects code decorrelated from any tools

Comment: ok, there is also an option in Jenkins while making a pipeline job to provide SCM details from where the Jenkinsfile should be picked (it can be a different SCM than the one that needs to be built).
It also gives you an option to specify the branches you'd like to track. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built.
More details [link] (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline-in-scm)

Comment: if i configure the SCM details and give my jenkinsfile project url + credential. 
The branches that will be checked for build will be the jenkinsfile project not the codebase project no ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i managed to make it work.
In my jenkins pipeline, i activated "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket".

```
    node {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: 'feature/test-b']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, 
    parentCredentials: false, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', 
    trackingSubmodules: false]], submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'admin', 
    url: 'http://localhost:7990/scm/bout/boutique-a.git']]])
    }
```

When a change is made in boutique-a in the branch 'feature/test-b' my job is triggered which is cool.

Now i have this other issue, how can i trigger when change are made in **feature/***
It looks like i cannot access to env.BRANCH_NAME when im not in a multibranch pipeline